# Cannot find class in same jar during SBT build

Tags: sbt, classpath

I am trying to build an sbt plugin like [swagger2markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup), but I face an issue when executing this in sbt:

```
org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.fetchBeanClass(BeanHelper.java:549)
..snip..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:909)
```

So, trying to lookup the PropertiesConfiguration from a class within the same jar is failing. It seems that sbt runs tasks in a classloader that does not include dependencies. This happens when I run the task from the sbt console.

Comment: have you found the root cause? I'm getting exactly same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I managed in the end, was to invoke the task in a forked jvm process:

```
val runner: ScalaRun = initScoped(myTask.scopedKey, Defaults.runnerInit).value
val log: Logger = streams.value.log
val arguments = Seq()
runner.run(mainClass, classpath.map(_.data), arguments, log)
```

This worked for me when there was a main class available in the tool I was using.

Answer (score 0):

`commons-configuration2` is using `commons-lang3` to load the class file for `ConfigurationBuilder`. And `commons-lang` is trying to use `ClassLoader` from the current thread to perform the loading see [ClassUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#line.986), but it seems that sbt doesn't give you any guaranties about `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader`, see [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/v355o5fFPl0) for more details.

The workaround is to current thread classLoader manually, like:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
  PluignObject.getClass.getClassLoader
)
```

But to be honest, I'm not sure how safe is this solution.